# Continually updating a rendered Matplotlib training metrics plot to my display

Tags: python, matplotlib, rendering

I am trying to continually render an ML loss graph to my screen throughout training.

In a notebook, I'd simply use this (which is still bas for reasons I will describe):

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import numpy as np
...

epochs = 100
losses = []

for epoch in range(epochs):
  # Train for one epoch
  history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 1)

  # Record mean training loss of this epoch
  losses.append(np.mean(history.history['loss']))

  # Clear the output
  clear_output(wait = True)

  # Display the loss graph
  fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7, 7))
  plt.plot(losses)
  plt.xlim(0, len(losses) - 1)
  plt.xlabel("Epoch")
  plt.ylabel("Loss")
  plt.show()
```

However, if I instead wanted to render the step-wise loss, rather than the epoch-wise loss, it would require frequent updates to a more lengthy and complicated figure, requiring more time to reupdate the figure every step than to actually train. Running this from your local terminal is even worse, because you would have to manually close the graph that opens each time you render the plot of the training metric in question.

I'm looking for a more efficient way to render the display repeatedly, one that would function well on my local terminal.

A good example is the rendering function in OpenAI's gym module. This allows you to render a reinforcement learning environment. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py), they use pyglet to connect to my local display and render the current state. However, my case is different because I am plotting data of increasing length each time I render it. I'm skeptical to believe that the approach of simply using Pyglet will work. Intuitively, my predominant constraint is that I **can not** rerender the entire figure each step. Perhaps Matplotlib has a built-in method of updating figures to a display which is more optimized for this purpose?

Note that I'm aware of online things like Weights and Biases' wandb Python module, but I'd rather visualize my metrics to my own screen, rather than onto an online project.

**Edit:**

This works, but forces me to rerender the entire display, which is inefficient as the plot gets longer:

```
plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

...

# Run this each time you need to update
ax.cla()
ax.plot(updated_data)
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: Are matplotlib's Animations the thing you're looking for? https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/animation/animate_decay.html

Comment: No, I am looking for a live, updateable display

Comment: Hey if you don't mind can I know why you won't prefer an online platform like Weights and Biases over manually displaying it on your own screen?

Comment: Debugging is annoying. I only use wandb when I’m deploying a larger, finalized project.